# Django request inside urlpatterns

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have some custom variable passed to the request which comes from custom middleware. Now I need to include some application urls based on the custom variable value. So I want to get something like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    if request.myvar != False:
        url(r'^', include('specialapp.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('basicapps.urls')),
)
```

Comment: Since you are depending on the `request` object - which is more per page request, you might not want to include/exclude the available URLs at that point of time. You might want to handle that in the view - (redirections / 404, etc.. ) or have the Middleware do that for you.

Comment: I have application which take care of that. I just want to include that app if custom request variable is True but don't know how.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request - set `request.urlconf` to an alternative url configuration in your middleware's `process_request` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the @knbk comment seems the right way to go, there's another way to deal with your issue:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include('basicapps.urls')),
)

if request.myvar != False:
    urlpatterns.append(url(r'^', include('specialapp.urls')))
```

BTW it doesn't change a lot your intent. I'm just checking `request.myvar` outside the `urlpatterns` tuple and appending the right url when `request.myvar` isn't equals to `False`.